# Is it bad creating an adapter for recyclerview inside an onclick listener?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment which contains:

- A RecyclerView.
- NavigationView with an ItemSelected listener.
- Custom dialog with a recyclerview as layout.

Now my question is if it's bad if i constantly create a new RecyclerView **Adapter** for the RecyclerView each time an item is clicked?

**This is my code inside my fragment:**

```
mNavigationView1.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.ic_add:
                    final Dialog dialog;
                    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.all_playlists_dialog);
                    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                    RecyclerView recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDialog);
                    Main.playLists = Main.songs.playList;
                    PlayListAdapter playListAdapter = new PlayListAdapter(getActivity(),Main.playLists);
                    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(playListAdapter);
                    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new OnItemClickListeners(getActivity(), recyclerView, new OnItemClickListeners.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            try {
                                Main.songs.addToPlayList(getActivity(), Main.musicList.get(currentIndex).getId(), Main.playLists.get(position).getID());
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Song added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.i(TAG, "SONG ID: " + Main.musicList.get(currentIndex).getId() + "PLAYLIST ID: " + Main.playLists.get(position));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Is calling this each time when the button is clicked **bad**, is there another way to display a recyclerview inside a custom dialog or is this a correct way to do it?

```
PlayListAdapter playListAdapter = new PlayListAdapter(getActivity(),Main.playLists);
final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(playListAdapter);
```

Sometimes i get an error in logcat which says `RecyclerView Skipping Layout` but not sure if this is the reason?

Comment: does the source data displayed in the recyclerview vary between showing dialogs?

Comment: If you mean if the data changes then yes, i have a tab where i can create another playlist, and this will update Main.playLists in the code in my post.